# DisplayTag - create first page through Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, displaytag

**What I know how to do:**

**submit a search form through a regular request (not Ajax)**, and in the new result webpage, show the **first page** of a table (created by DisplayTag) that can be paginated by Ajax requests (to enable Ajax with DisplayTag I use the jQuery plagin [displaytag-ajax](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/displaytag-ajax) ).

**What I want to do but do not know how:**

I want to create the **first page** of the table (based on the submitted search form) by Ajax. I.e., I want to **submit the search form through Ajax** and create the first page of the Ajax-paginable result table in the same webpage of the search form, without loading a new webpage.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to load the response from an AJAX request to a given URL into a div, and you can use the [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to transform the set of inputs of your search form into a query string.

The JSP page used to generate the first page of the table should just generate the table:

```
<%@ page ...%>
<%@ taglib ...%>
<display:table>
    ...
</display:table>
```

Comment: I do not have a problem with sending (by Ajax) the search form to the server. But you assume that the response from the Ajax request is an HTML string created by DisplayTag. But right now my java code only create a Java list of objects to show on the first table page. You did not explain how I convert (during an Ajax request) this list to an HTML string - how do I do in my Java code something like `Sting tableHTML = DisplayTag.createTableHTML(resultList);` ??

Comment: You do it like you do for a standard request. Dispatch to a JSP, and this JSP will generate the HTML table (and only the HTML table) using the displaytag. This HTML table will then be sent in the response, and the JavaScript will include the table into the DOM.

Comment: this makes sense. But I am not sure how the generated HTML table can be grabbed by the Java code after the dispatch. Could you please provide some sample code for this?

Comment: Why do you want to grab the generated HTML in the Java code? The generated HTML is sent to the HTTP response, just as it is for a regular HTTP request. The only difference is that you send only a portion of the HTML page, and not the full HTML page.

Comment: I see - so I guess I am not sure how to dispatch to a JSP page, from a Spring controller method that handles the Ajax request (what should the controller method return in this case?) - could you provide the basic code for this?

Comment: What does the controller do for a regular form submission which returns the full page? You said in your question that you knew how to do that. Do exactly the same thing, but with a JSP that generates just the table, as shown in my answer. A regular request and an AJAX request are the same thing. The only difference is what the browser does with the response.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. On the controller side, I should handle the request just like any ordinary HTTP request. For some reason I came to think that I would need to use `request.getRequestDispatcher("jspfile").forward(request, response);`. Instead, my controller method code should actually be something like: `public String ajaxResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    request.setAttribute("command", "hello world");
    return "jspfile";
}
` -- which is again, what that you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to submit your form via AJAX. When the response is received, [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) the form from the DOM and [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) the response.

Comment: The problem is with the response I receive. My java code gets (from the database) a list of the objects I want to show on the first table page. But according to your answer there is a way to use this list in order to create an HTML table (based on the list the the DisplayTag tags in my JSP file) - DisplayTag does this translation for me during a regular request, but I do not know how to this translation during an Ajax request - obviously I will have to access the JSP code from the java code (?) --- do you know how to do this? Or am I missing something here.

Comment: An AJAX request and a regular request are the same thing for the server. Just generate your displaytag table as you would do for a regular request. The only difference is that the HTML generated by the AJAX request should only include the table, and not all the HTML code before and after the table.